# Securely registering a new Wordpress user with a custom Zapier action (via JSON API?)

Tags: json, wordpress, authentication, zapier

I want to use Zapier to register a new Wordpress user — the trigger will be a new purchase on Gumroad.

This plugin — https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/ — allows you to register users using a public JSON interface, eg by hitting

```
https://example.com/api/user/register/?username={{email}}&email={{email}}&nonce=blahblahblah
```

I'm new to all this, but know that I can get Zapier to insert the purchaser's email from Gumroad into `{{email}}`.

My question is, how can I do this in a secure way?

(At the moment anyone can hit `example.com.com/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register` and get the key they need)

And maybe it can even be done without using Zapier?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the nonce is only good for a short period of time, like a couple minutes? If so, what you want to do is lock down the `/api/get_nonce/` endpoint to require a password. That way only authenticated users can get a nonce, which can then be used to create the user.

As for how Zapier fits in, it's a bit complicated to custom build a two-request process like this. You would have to make your own app on the Developer Platform do the nonce call and then the user creation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Brian, and yes the nonce has a limited lifespan.

Comment: Using Zapier is nice because it can automate the entire process (sending the data between the two apps). If you don't want to create your own Zapier app (for the "action" side) you can always try using a generic "webhook" action that can send the Gumroad data (including the email) into a script you control, then just do the API call from there.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following plugin to create users (via Zapier) on my WordPress sites after someone signed up on my Teachable school: [WP Webhooks Pro](https://ironikus.com/)

This plugin allows me to either POST the data to my WordPress site via JSON, XML or a simple form data. In my case, I don't need a nonce, since the plugin generates API keys that I can use to push my data to.